# vba: Do same code in all sheets

Tags: vba, foreach

Simple question. The following code works fine:

```
Dim hoja as worksheet
For Each hoja In Workbooks("Origen.xlsx").Worksheets
Msgbox hoja.name
next
```

However, the following code does NOT work. Can anybody say why and make it work?

```
Dim hoja as worksheet
For Each hoja In Workbooks("Origen.xlsx").Worksheets
Range("a1:a2").copy Destination:=Range("a3:a4")
next
```

The second code only does the copy/paste thing in one of the sheets, but not in all. 
Please can you help? I'm so frustrated with such a simple thing.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `hoja.Range` instead of simply `Range`.

Answer (score 1):

The `Range` object, if not qualified, always refers to active sheet.
If you want to copy paste each time on different sheet, use the code below:

```
Dim hoja as worksheet
For Each hoja In Workbooks("Origen.xlsx").Worksheets
hoja.Range("a1:a2").copy Destination:=hoja.Range("a3:a4")
next
```

Comment: Thank you Branislav, so simple, still I couln't see it :S. Thanks!!

Comment: @Mario You`re welcome. Obvious things are the easiest to overlook.